# how to add grid under a tab in magento custom admin module?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to create a grid in my custom module under a tab section as like would show up  under `customer ->wish list` tab.

Comment: can you provide a little more detail? What have you tried? What code are you working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your using **Method 3** @ http://www.nextbits.eu/blog/how-to-add-tab-in-customer-information-in-magento-admin/

```
class Namespace_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Tab
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface {
   /**
     * Set the template for the block
     *
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
       $this->setTemplate('modulename/customer/tab.phtml');
    }
```

in modulename/customer/tab.phtml

```
<?php 
  echo $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('modulename/adminhtml_modulename_grid')
            ->toHtml();
?>
```

Comment: I have already created tab in my custom module. Now I want to add grid into my tab as like coming wishlist tab under customer portion.

Comment: Did your create the grid in modulename/adminhtml/modulename/grid.php?